# Executor service full initialisation guarantee

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a hashmap and a complex object initialised and updated in main thread.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1","val1");
map.put("key2","val2");
map.put("key3","va3");
map.put("key4","val4");

ComplexObject c1 = new ComplexObject();
c1.setPropert1(prop1);c1.setProperty2(map);

ExecutorService executorService  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

executorService.submit(()->{
    Map<String,String> m = c1.getProperty2();
    String val = m.get("key1"); //1
    //do something
});
```

Is thread submitted in excutor service guranteed to see val as val1 on line 1 or it can be Hashmap initialised in main thread is not yet fully initialsed due to instruction reordering and thread submitted in pool can get val as null.?

What should I do to make sure threads submitted in pool get Complex object c1 fully intialised and all its properties are also fully set whether they are hashmap or further complex objects.

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation to [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` or `Callable` task to an `ExecutorService` [*happen-before*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) any actions taken by that task, which in turn *happen-before* the result is retrieved via `Future.get()`.

So, yes, `map` and `c1` will be fully initialized to the task submitted later in the same thread.

Comment: So why do we force to have all our properties as final or initialisation do be done in synchronized block ? My point is if say due to instruction reordering main thread has not yet performed action of compling c1's constructor and putting values in m1 and called executor.submit before that(due to instruction reorder) . Now will thread get key as null. since action is not yet done in main thread will be done in main thread when main thread require to access c1.getProperty2().get("key1") ?

Comment: @user1846749 Your concern is perfectly valid with regards to normal sharing between threads. But there are certain actions that are guaranteed to prevent visibility problems, like synchronization, accessing a `volatile` variable or starting a thread. `ExecutorService` uses these mechanisms to ensure proper visibility for new tasks. See the second link above for more details.

Comment: So if instead of executor service say I would have done .  
Thread t = new MyThread(ComplexObjectc2);
t.start();

---
In thread t - 
access complextobject2 - I could get complextobject2.getpropert2() as null ??

Comment: @user1846749 That would be equally safe, as long as you start the thread after the initialization. And since you're only *creating* the `ExecutorService` after your initialization, all threads in that service have the same guarantee simply by virtue of their starting later. So you're actually covered from two angles.

Comment: Say if executor service is created before initialisation of complex object as first line of main method. So threads are started earlier  and then I initiialise my complex object and call submit - will it make problem now while accessing complex object since threads were started earlier.

Comment: @user1846749 That's still safe, because `ExecutorService` offers a separate guarantee for task submission. I was just pointing out that in your case you have a *double* guarantee.

Comment: so in short making members as final is not required for ensuring full initialisation of object if you are sharing it among threads submitted to executor service ? Since executor service is itself taking care of that.

Comment: @user1846749 If you're sharing it between *other* threads, you need take responsibility for that. But the thread executing your task will be fine.

Comment: Did not get this - can you give an example difference between two scenarios ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133178/discussion-between-shmosel-and-user1846749).